# Does reproductivity of chi-square imply independence?

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be two random variable s.t. $X\thicksim \chi^2(m),Y\thicksim \chi^2(n)$ and $X+Y\thicksim\chi^2(m+n)$, does $X,Y$ always be independent?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you may take a look at Cochran's theorem

Comment: @BGM yes, but simply a chi-square distribution r.v. need not to be a sum of some normal distribution r,v,

Answer (score 0):

One way can be as follows..

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then their joint distribution$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\chi ^2(m)\times \chi ^2 (n)$$

From the convolution formula $$f_{X+Y}(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(k,s-k)\ dk$$ find out $f_{X+Y}$. IF this matches with the given. Supposition is correct. Otherwise false..

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim \chi^2_n$ and $Y\sim\chi^2_m$ and $X,Y$ are independent then $X+Y\sim\chi^2_{m+n}$, so if the question is whether it can happen, then the answer is "yes".  A different question is this: If $X\sim \chi^2_n$ and $Y\sim\chi^2_m$ and $X+Y\sim\chi^2_{m+n}$, does it necessarily follow that $X,Y$ are independent?  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean..